# kendo drop down return object object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with kendo drop-down list.Drop down  returns the object object, but i need string. Can somebody help me. Here codes. I'm sorry for my english, i'm from Russia

MyScript.js:(get data from Admin controller)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({

        dataSource: {
            type: 'odata',
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true,

            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/Admin",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                },
                create: {
                    url: "/api/Admin",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                update: {
                    url: function (AdminModel) {
                        return "/api/Admin/" + "?roles=" + AdminModel.Roles
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "PUT"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: function (AdminModel) {
                        return "/api/Admin/" + "?name=" + AdminModel.Name
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "DELETE"
                },
                parameterMap: function (model, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && model) {
                        return kendo.stringify(model);
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    if (response.value !== undefined)
                        return response.value;
                    else {
                        delete response["odata.metadata"];
                        return response;
                    }
                },
                total: function (response) {
                    return response['odata.count'];
                },
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { editable: false },
                        Name: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        Roles: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        NewRole: { type: "string" },

                    }
                }
            }
        },


        height: 560,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        editable: "popup",
        columns: [
           { field: "ID", width: 50 },
           { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 120 },
           { field: "Roles", title: "Roles", width: 120},
           { field: "NewRole", hidden:true,title: "NewRole", editor: RoleDropDownEditor, template: "#=NewRole#" },
           { command: ["destroy", "edit"], title: " ", width: "120px" }
        ]
    });
});
My Drop Down List(get data from Role controller)
function RoleDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required  data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({

            dataTextField: "Role",
            dataValueGield: "Id",
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {

                        url: "/api/Role",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",

                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                Id:{type:"string"},
                                Role: { type: "string" }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

        });
}
```

**Controller**

```
Web API class Role.cs

    using MyCMS.Models;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MyCMS.Controllers
{
    public class RoleController : ApiController
    {
        private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

        public class MyRole
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Role { get; set; }
        }

        // GET api/usermanage

        public List<MyRole> Get()
        {
            var result = new List<MyRole>();
            foreach (var role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
            {
                result.Add(new MyRole{ Id = role, Role = role});
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    <head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<div id="grid"></div>

@section Scripts{

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/2013.2.716/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Admin")

}
```

Comment: `dataValueGield: "Id"` is misspelled...

Comment: Thank you. Did not notice the error. But he still returns object object

Comment: `foreach (var role in Roles.GetAllRoles()) {...}` -- what data type is `role` in this statement?

Comment: and 'result' is array.  'Web Api return <RoleController.MyRole>
<Role>Admin</Role>
</RoleController.MyRole>
<RoleController.MyRole>
<Role>Reader</Role>
</RoleController.MyRole>
<RoleController.MyRole>
<Role>Writer</Role>
</RoleController.MyRole>
</ArrayOfRoleController.MyRole>'

Answer (score 17):

Check out this [post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlistfor-return-value-of-object-object-#UWutovNBR0GadH4CSFfRLw) and this [Kendo Doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-valuePrimitive).  Setting the ValuePrimitive to 'true' solved this problem for me.

Apparently if the field in your model is null, Kendo tries to assign the whole item to the field.  Setting the ValuePrimitive to true prevents that and it just assigns the value field instead.

Comment: Finally! - Took me three days to find this answer

Comment: Thanks, Justin. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdownlist's datasource isn't configured correctly. You have defined the schema within the transport. This isn't where it needs to be. You put a closing curly brace in the wrong spot. Here is how it should look:

```
dataSource: {
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "/api/Role",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json"
    }
  },  // YOU WERE MISSING THIS
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {
        Id: { type: "string" },
        Role: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  }
  // REMOVED AN INCORRECTLY PLACED } FROM HERE
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All that you have to do is to add the kendo javascript files
like kendo.all.min.js and kendo.default.min.js
to the head section of the layout page